# Overriding ComboBox to select item by pressing index through keyboard in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I want to override a combobox such that it can be selected by its position in the list by pressing key through keyboard.

**Example:**

```
ComboBoxMonths
  - Jan
  - Feb
  - Mar
  - Apr
  - May
  - Jun
  . . .
```

When **'J'** is pressed **Jan** is selected, and **'F'** for **'Feb'**,....

I want to use it like this, when

**1** is pressed then **Jan** ,
**2** for **Feb** , etc.

Is it possible ? If yes, How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Isn't there a KeyDown/KeyUp event on the ComboBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only works properly if the combo is set to DropDownList, which makes sense in your example.  It also only covers 1-9.  If you want to handle more than one digit, it requires more logic with timers.

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        var index = e.KeyChar - '1';
        if( index >= 0 && index < this.Items.Count )
            this.SelectedIndex = index;

        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```